# how to draw Password field just the way we draw Ember.TextField?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js

in ember view handlebars i can draw the text field as {{view Em.TextField}} but what is the way to draw the password input field?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For current versions of Ember:

`{{input type="password"}}`

Old answer, valid for pre-1.0 versions of Ember:

`{{view Ember.TextField type="password"}}`

Answer (score 2):

All late, but for other people finding this answer, this works for newer ember versions:

```
{{input type="password"}}
```